# How to change the border style of a form element in itext8

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7

Using itext7, .NET, I can change the border style of a form element [with this code](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/support-for-beveled-underline-and-inset-form-field-border-styles):

```
PdfFormField formField2 = PdfTextFormField.CreateText(doc,
            new Rectangle(100, 500, 100, 50), "secondField", "Hello, iText!");
formField2.GetWidgets()[0].SetBorderStyle(PdfAnnotation.STYLE_UNDERLINE);
```

In itext Core 8.0.0, I have to use the field's annotation - it has a function `SetBorderStyle`, but I could not find out what to set as parameters in the call; it requests a `PdfDictionary`:

```
  PdfFormAnnotation ann1 = form.GetField("PatName").GetFirstFormAnnotation();
  ann1.SetVisibility(PdfFormAnnotation.HIDDEN); // Works
  //ann1.SetBorderStyle(PdfAnnotation.STYLE_UNDERLINE); // Bad syntax
  //ann1.SetBorderStyle(new PdfAnnotationBorder(0.,0.,0. ));
```